# Create templates for Calendar?

Tags: calendar, macos

Suppose my weekly schedule can be broken down into 3 prototype days: `work1`, `work2` and `week_end`. Suppose also that I cannot really plan much in advance which *type* each day will be. Is there a way to create templates that I can add day by day to my Calendar? Each day *type* would consist of a series of events.

Comment: It will remember previous events & suggest them as you start to type. perhaps you could add three some time in the past with generic defaults for each type, called 'work1' etc then use that to recall your defaults??

Comment: I just realised you probably mean a slew of individual events during one day… in which case, I doubt that can be done.

Comment: Yes exactly. What a pity

Comment: You can multi-select, then copy, switch to month view, click a date & paste them all at once. They will paste to the currently-selected calendar.